# componentDidMount fire twice when navigate using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a async call in componentDidMount, when I refresh the page, it worked as expected, but when I navigate from the elsewhere enter the page, it called twice my async action, I have no clue why, below is my code.

```
export default class EditorWrap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loadedS3Credential: false
    }

    this.config = {
      placeholderText: 'edit here'
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.loadedS3Credential) {

      console.log('fire')

      const imageUploadToS3 = await axios('/signS3').then(resp => resp.data)
      if (imageUploadToS3) {
        this.config = {
          ...this.config,
          imageUploadToS3
        }

        this.setState({
          loadedS3Credential: true
        })
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.loadedS3Credential) return null

    return (
      <EditorBody
        config={this.config}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide the code where you render `< EditorWrap ../>` component please, the problem is probably there

Answer (score 0):

you are using async method it will call twice or more in a component. Just remove that then your problem will be resolved.

Happy Coding !

Comment: It doesn't relate at all to the async, `componentDidMount` should be called once